# Custom Metrics in Google Analytics Displaying in Multiples of 1,000,000

Tags: google-analytics

I have been using Google Analytics all year and recently all of my custom metrics have started displaying in multiples of $1,000,000. I have checked the tracking code and even when I monitor network traffic the correct values are being sent across. Even my previous data from several months ago has now been multiplied by $1,000,000. I am thinking that it could be a bug in GA. Has anyone else had this issue or know a solution?

NOTE: I am also having this problem (Unsure if its related) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855850/google-analytics-multiple-tracking-codes-on-the-same-domain

EDIT - IMAGE

[image]

Comment: Have you imported any data?

Comment: No it is just coming from the site.

Comment: Are you using Custom Metrics? And are you having any issues?

Comment: In accounts I have access to everything seems fine. Are you sure you are reffering to custom metrics?

Comment: Yes im sure - I have just attached an image

Comment: What im thinking is that if its an error caused by me then previous data would not have changed.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I suppose it was a Google Analytics Bug. Today I logged in and everything was fine. It was no longer displaying the data in multiples of 1,000,000. No one else in my team was working on this so nothing was changed in the code.

Dam you Google, you wasted my a lot of my time :(